# Use alpha of one texture node to mask another texture node

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I have two texture nodes for my object. I'm using the "normal" node to create a bump map by connecting the "color" output of texture1 to the "normal" input of the "normal" node and taking the output to the "displacement" in "material output".

Now I need to apply the displacement only to those areas that are transparent in texture2. How can I use the alpha channel of texture2 to mask out texture1 before it goes to the input of the normal node?

Answer (score 4):

I think I got it:

I used a mix RGB node and put my texture1 into the upper slot and a transparent color into the lower slot. Then I put the alpha of texture2 into the "fac" of the mix node.

Comment: A screenshot of your node setup may prove helpful to other people who want to achieve this. Also, if this indeed solves your problem, you should mark your answer as the accepted one.

Comment: @SixthOfFour There is time constraint before you can accept your own answer, I think it is two days.

Comment: @NoviceInDisguise Oh. I didn't know that.